# Qiskit NameError: name 'q0' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, qiskit

I wrote the following code to implement the Grover's algorithm using 3-qubits.

```
from qiskit import*
from qiskit.tools.visualization import*

list = [q0,q1,q2]
def ccz(qci,q0,q1,q2):
    qci.h(q2)
    qci.ccx(q0,q1,q2)
    qci.h(q2)
def grover(qci,q0,q1,q2):
    ccz(qci,q0,q1,q2)
    for i in range(list):
        qci.h(i)
        qci.x(i)
    ccz(qci,q0,q1,q2)
    for i in range(list):
        qci.x(i)
        qci.h(i)

bn = 3
q = QuantumRegister(bn)
c = ClassicalRegister(bn)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q,c)
for i in range(bn):
    qc.h(q[i])
grover(qc,q[0],q[1],q[2])
for i in range(bn):
    qc.measure(q[bn-i-1],c[i])
r = execute(qc,"local_qasm_simulator").result()
rc = r.get_counts()
print(rc)
plot_histogram(rc)
```

But I got the error below.  Why did my Jupyter notebook care only about "q0", not other elements in the list? How can I fix this?

```
NameError: name 'q0' is not defined
```

Comment: what is error stack trace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you error about `q0` because this is the first unknown variable that it encounters. Then it dies.

There is improper flow in your program. You try to define the variable `list`:

- you try to build it from the variables that are not defined yet,
- you make it global and try to operate somehow in the functions, where you pass also pass variables as parameters,
- this name `list` is not a good choice as it's a python built-in name.

Try this one:

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit.tools.visualization import *

def ccz(qci, q0, q1, q2):
    qci.h(q2)
    qci.ccx(q0, q1, q2)
    qci.h(q2)


def grover(qci, q0, q1, q2):
    ccz(qci, q0, q1, q2)
    for i in [q0, q1, q2]:
        qci.h(i)
        qci.x(i)
    ccz(qci, q0, q1, q2)
    for i in [q0, q1, q2]:
        qci.x(i)
        qci.h(i)

bn = 3
q = QuantumRegister(bn)
c = ClassicalRegister(bn)
qc = QuantumCircuit(q, c)
for i in range(bn):
    qc.h(q[i])
grover(qc, q[0], q[1], q[2])
for i in range(bn):
    qc.measure(q[bn - i - 1], c[i])
r = execute(qc, "local_qasm_simulator").result()
rc = r.get_counts()
print(rc)
plot_histogram(rc)
```